# gpg encryption in xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

I am trying to encrypt a .csv file using gpg in `xp_cmdshell` command in `sql server 2012`.
When I use gpg through `xp_cmdshell`, it says gpg is not recognized as an internal or external command.
But this works perfectly on windows cmd.
How should I configure my sql server to accept this command. Please advice.

```
select @encrypt = 'gpg -e -r ' + @sEncryptionKey+ ' '+ @sPath + @tempdataFolder+'\'+ @sFileName 

exec master..xp_cmdshell @encrypt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remedy the error you are indicating above, simply add the full path to gpg.exe in your code.

```
select @encrypt = 'c:\gpg\gpg.exe -e -r ' + @sEncryptionKey+ ' '+ @sPath + @tempdataFolder+'\'+ @sFileName 

exec master..xp_cmdshell @encrypt
```

For comparison, this is how I have done this in the past via SSIS; be sure you provide the exact full path to your executable... we are using gpg4win (gpg2.exe) in this example.

You may also want to wrap each parameter in " " to handle file names/paths with spaces better.

```
DECLARE @sKeyEmail VARCHAR(100), @sInFile VARCHAR(100), @sOutFile VARCHAR(100), @SQL VARCHAR(1000)

SET @sInFile = 'c:\temp\somefile.xls'
SET @sOutFile = 'c:\temp\somefile.xls.gpg'
SET @sKeyEmail = 'user@domain.com'


SET @SQL = 'EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''C:\Progra~1\GNU\GnuPG\gpg2 -o ' +@sOutFile+ ' -e -r ' +@sKeyEmail + ' ' +@sInFile+ ''''

PRINT @SQL
-- EXEC sp_execute @SQL
```

Comment: I get a new error message saying C:\ is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: ok, i modified the sql by adding " " to the path and now it is  select encrypt = '"c:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpg2.exe" -e -r ' + sEncryptionKey+ ' '+ sPath + tempdataFolder+'\'+ sFileName  and now i get Encryption failed no public key

Comment: That means the email you are passing for the key isn't recognised by the key manager...  if xp_cmdshell is running as a service account you have to install the key for use under those credentials.  In gpg4win, you'd install the key in Kleopatra, I think there is an option to install for everyone when you mark it as "trusted".

Comment: Keep in mind xp_cmdshell runs under the same credentials sqlserver.exe does -- not your credentials.

Comment: I have installed the key in Gpa in gpg4win. I just need to import the key. When i open kleopatra, i can see that the key has been registered with the email address i am passing in the trusted certificate tab. I run sql.exe with my windows credentials. What else do i need to change

Comment: In kleopatra, right click the certificate, pick `certify certificate` and certify "for everyone to see".  The user account running SQLServer.exe (or the proxy account if you're using one) must have visibility to the certificate.  To check credentials, you can run `whoami` via xp_cmdshell to see what account is used.

Comment: select @encrypt = '"c:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpg2.exe" -e -r key' + ' '+sPath +tempdataFolder+'\'+ sFileName takes too long to respond. where as select encrypt = '"c:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpg2.exe" --list-keys ' excecutes in 2 secs

Comment: Not sure if you got this working as you accepted the answer -- if its still not completing, I'd make sure its not waiting for user input in the shell.

Comment: How do i know if its waiting for the user input. is there any way i can know about it?

Comment: You'd have to run the command in a command prompt under the same credentials manually.

Comment: ok so when I do that, it encrypts perfectly. it does not even a take a sec and does not wait for user input.

Comment: Thank for your help though. You were very helpful. will update you if i come across solution sooner or later.

Comment: is there any way to suppress the prompt for user input?

Comment: when i run the same query in cmd, it encrypts the file in no time. buit the same query does not complete in cmdshell. Strange!!

Comment: When I do a whoami it returns, nt service\mssqlserver

Comment: when we create and import a key from cmd windows , where does it store the key ring

Comment: This is getting out of hand, one of my first comments was about using the same credentials to test...  You need to setup a proxy account for xp_cmdshell and login to windows as that account -- setup kleopatra, get it all working, then change SQL to use that proxy account.  I will not be replying again.